# How can i read a clipboard data and store it to browser local storage

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, local-storage, clipboard

I am building a chrome extention where it will pick the last copied data from clipboard and then push to localstorage of the browser. How can i acheive that?

I tried this but this is not working at all on my end

```js
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {

});

chrome.clipboard.onClipboardDataChanged.addListener(() => {
      chrome.clipboard.readText((copiedText) => {
          if (copiedText) {
            const copiedData = {
              label: copiedText,
              url: window.location.href
              copiedDataArray.push(copiedData);

              chrome.storage.local.set({
                copiedDataArray
              });
            }
          });
      });
    console.log(copiedDataArray)
```

Comment: In JS you would normally leverage the Navigator and Window objects.

Comment: I would expect `localStorage.setItem('somekey',JSON.stringify( copiedDataArray));`

Comment: Also your `const copiedData = {` is not closed and your addListener does not have content

Comment: Due to bugs in Chrome this won't work. Use document.execCommand in the offscreen document, use [this example](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-extensions-samples/tree/main/functional-samples/cookbook.offscreen-clipboard-write) replacing `clipboardWrite` with `clipboardRead`, `copy` with `paste`, and onClipboardDataChanged with setInterval.